# Why is it that LoadParams.requestedLoadSize returns the specified page size to LivePagedListBuilder times 3?

Tags: android, pagination, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am creating a `PagedList` using:

`LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, 20)`

Inside my implementation of `PageKeyedDataSource`, `loadParams.requestedLoadSize` returns 60. I tried with other numbers, and it seems that `loadParams.requestedLoadSize` always returns the page size I specified times three.

Anyone has any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: because default `PagedList.Config` forces that - use `LivePagedListBuilder(Factory<Key, Value> dataSourceFactory, PagedList.Config config)` if you dont like it

Comment: @pskink You're right. Turns out `PagedList.Config` has `setPageSize` and `setInitialLoadSizeHint`, the latter being used as the initial page size. Nice option to have but I think it is counterintuitive to have it be different than the informed page size as a default value. Anyway, thanks a lot. Do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: oh, post a self answer with some detailed extra info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried with other numbers, and it seems that loadParams.requestedLoadSize always returns the page size I specified times three.

This is because `params.requestedLoadSize` on `loadInitial` is different.

What you have passed on the second parameter of LivePagedListBuilder is pageSize, not loadInitial.

```
LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, 20)
```

I have notice the same behaviour on RxPagedListBuilder.

```
RxPagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, 20)
```

As you guess, the loadInitial size is three times of pageSize.

If you want to setup the loadInitial, you have to pass `PagedList.Config` to the second parameter of LivedPagedListBuilder or RxPagedListBuilder.

```
RxPagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory,
    PagedList.Config.Builder()                
    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE)
    .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
    .build()
).buildObservable()
```

Comment: I am wondering what is the use of pagesize and initialiliadsizehint. even if i have set the page size as 10 and send 20 data from server in frist call it gives me a set of 20. so what is this pagesize being used for?

Comment: Thanks, i was also tried of debugging why the number was increased 3 times every first load.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `PagingConfig` you can set `initialLoadSize` to the number you need to set at the first time when loading the list

```
Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = PAGE_SIZE,
            initialLoadSize = 10 //if you need to load 10 items at the first time
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behavior of `PagedList`. If you check the source code of [PagedList.kt#763](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/paging/source/androidx/paging/PagedList.kt;drc=327bd5c1133428337208d73268019969690f8b48;l=763) for `loadInitial` the page size is multiplied by `DEFAULT_INITIAL_PAGE_MULTIPLIER` which value is `3` and after `loadInitial` all the calls will be made using the `params.requestedLoadSize` value